# How to solve an error which appears when I switch scenes?

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit, transition

I created a game with 3 Scenes(1.mainMenu, 2.Settings, 3.gameScene).I can´t solve an error which appears every time I tap on the homeButton(from the Settings scene to go back to the mainMenu) to switch scenes and than the app crashes. 
I use the same principle in another Scene (from gameScene to mainMenu) and there it works well, but why not in the other?

The error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here the Settings Scene:

```
class Settings: SKScene{
 let backToMenuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BlackArrow1.0")

 override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)
        if atPoint(locationUser) == backToMenuButton {
            let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.2)
            let mainMenu1 = mainMenu(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(mainMenu1, transition: transition)
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: is your mainMenu class really named with a lowercase m, might be your problem. If your class IS named with a lowercase m you should fix that. Classes should be named with Camel case with the first letter being capitalized

Comment: The error message you showed is not descriptive enough. What does it say before `terminating...`?

Comment: I've seen those kinds of dylib debug prints before and they can be annoying because it doesn't really give you any information.  Have you tried to set a breakpoint to catch all exceptions?  If not, go to breakpoints tab(cmd+7) you will see a "+" bottom left select exception breakpoint.  Then trigger your scene change, and it should catch the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: The programm show the line from another button: "self.addChild(ratingButton)" from the mainMenu. @Jacob Boyd

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks for the tipp @Jacob Boyd appreciate it!